# How to retrieve contents from different categories using rss in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

There is a wordpress web site which has categories news (514), announcements (1370), culture (770), sports(771), education(772). Numbers are the category ids.

This web site gives RSS feeds and I can retrieve news contents using `http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&cat=514` and so on.

I want to grab all three culture, sports and education contents at once.

I have tried some urls like

`http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&cat=770,771,772`

and

`http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&cat={770,771,772}`

but did got only the first id's contents.

Is there another solution for this problem?

PS: I am not managing that web site. So I cannot make settings on it.

Comment: maybe an array is allowed? not sure maybe `http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&cat[]=770&cat[]=771&cat[]=772` something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for wasting your time.

`http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&cat=770,771,772`

works.

It is just my inattention.